# Миниатюра в записях wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии появлялся `lightbox` а не тупо переход на ссылку картинки.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { // 
    $large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image[0] . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Есть у меня дополнительные маленьки тумбы

```
<?php if ( wpsc_the_product_thumbnail() ) : ?>

<?php
    sb_get_images_for_product(wpsc_the_product_id()); ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_permalink() ); ?>">
                                    <img class="no-image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="No Image" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo WPSC_CORE_THEME_URL; ?>wpsc-images/noimage.png" width="<?php echo get_option('product_image_width'); ?>" height="<?php echo get_option('product_image_height'); ?>" />
                                    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Вот у них стоит `lightbox`, никак не могу сделать так чтобы главная миниатюра тоже выводилась как лайтбокс